# Question about how arrays stored in memory

Tags: arrays, c

I'm a beginner in c language and programming, I heard that an array's elements were stored in successive memory location.

1. if I somehow manage to make memory location like this:[image: memory drawing] what will happen if I declare an `int8_t arr[2]`, will it go wrong?
2. does compiler have a list of the allocated memory and check when it declares variable?
3. calling `malloc(1)` in a while loop, why their return value has the difference of 0x20?

thanks for your helping!

Comment: 1. Why should `int arr[2]` go wrong. I didn't understand the question. 2. It's the compiler's job. Didn't really get the question either. 3. `malloc` allocates memory, but there is a lot of internal book keeping to be done, so it's quite normal that each chunk of memory allocated via malloc actually uses more bytes than actually allocated. 4. I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about, which irrelevant part of your code?

Comment: Could you please show what you mean by code, a [mcve]. Also, the 3rd question seems unrelated to first two.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm a beginner in c language and programming, I heard that an array's
> elements were stored in successive memory locations.

How the memory allocation process works is left to the implementation. Every compiler, hardware port or version may do this completely different way. So you can't assume that the arrays will be placed in the successive memory location.

But the array is a continuous chunk of memory and elements are stored one after another so you can use element type pointer arithmetic to calculate references.

> if I somehow manage to stuff values in every 8-bit location (like
> buttons on the flute, sorry for my broken English). what will happen
> if I declare an int arr[2], will it go wrong?

I do not understand what you mean, but if you want to store 8 bits of data use the array of `int8_t`. Use the correct type for the job. `int8_t array[2]` and you will have an array of the two 8 bits integer numbers.

> how the compiler knows which location is allocated?

I think it is much too early for you to think about the compiler design. At the moment simply assume that it happens magically behind the scenes.

> calling malloc(1) in a while loop, why their return value has the
> difference of 0x20?

Because it is how your malloc function works. Another implementation may work a completely different way and some will return addresses not related to the previous one.

> will the irrelevant part of my code executed at the same time to save
> the time?

The code will be executed exactly as you wrote it, but if you do not have processes/tasks nothing in your code will execute in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Given the declaration

```
int a[5];
```

you get something like this in memory (each square represents an `int` object):

```
   +---+
a: |   | a[0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
   |   | a[2]
   +---+
   |   | a[3]
   +---+
   |   | a[4]
   +---+
```

That's it - no other metadata regarding size or type or starting address is stored as part of the array.  All you get is a contiguous sequence of objects of the specified type.  There is no object `a` that's separate from the array elements themselves.

> what will happen if I declare an `int8_t arr[2]`, will it go wrong?

Not sure what you mean.  Declarations are not processed at runtime; during translation, the compiler analyzes the code and generates the machine code necessary to set aside any storage at program or function entry.

> does compiler have a list of the allocated memory and check when it declares variable?

*During translation*, the compiler will keep track of declarations (using what's often called a *symbol table*) and will issue any diagnostics if the declaration isn't valid (incomplete type, no size, syntax error, whatever).  No such checks are done at runtime.

> calling `malloc(1)` in a while loop, why their return value has the difference of 0x20?

Because unless you're also calling `free()` on the memory you allocated, you're allocating a *new* block of memory every time through the loop, each of which starts at a different address.

Depending on the implementation, `malloc` may allocate more memory than necessary for the given object to store bookkeeping information about that object.  After all, when you call `free`, all you give it is the starting address of the memory you allocated - you don't tell it *how much* memory to free.  That information has to be stored somewhere, and many implementations set aside some extra space prior to the allocated block to do so:

```
+---+ ---+
|   |    | 
+---+    |
 ...     +---- bookkeeping data
+---+    |
|   |    |
+---+ ---+
|   |    | <--- this byte's address returned by malloc
+---+    |
|   |    |
+---+    +---- Requested block
 ...     |
+---+    | 
|   |    |
+---+ ---+
```

Answer (score -1):

1. An array is a collection of a data type stored in memory. When you declare an array like:

```
int arr[2];
```

Your compiler allocates `2 * sizeof(int)` amount of memory in RAM and the pointer to the beginning of that memory is used when `arr` is referenced. I don't know what could go wrong or what you mean by "will it go wrong?"

2. Compiler knows the location of the allocated array because compiler is the one to allocate it in the first place. The place is already (mostly) determined by the compiler.
3. Calling `malloc` in a while loop is different from declaring an array such as `int arr[2]`. `malloc` is a function which allocates some space on the heap. Heap is a special memory allocated for the dynamic use in a program. The space for heap is provided by the OS and this space is divided into smaller chunks by the implementation of `malloc`. The reason that there is `0x20` difference between the addresses that there may be a heap entry for each malloc you do. For example think of a heap entry such as:

```
0x1000 : 4 Bytes stores the size of the data inside the entry
0x1004 : 8 Bytes stores a pointer to the next entry 
0x100C : 8 Bytes some other data that maybe used in heap entry
0x1014 : 4 Bytes the integer itself
0x1018 : The start of the next entry etc.
```

4. I do not know what that means.

Edit: For all those who say that arrays are not pointers. Consider the following code:

```
int someArrFunc()
{
    int arr[2];
    int *ptr = arr;

    arr[0] = 451;
    *ptr = 885;

    arr[1] = 452;
    *++ptr = 886;

    int abc = sizeof(arr);
}
```

If we compiled this code the disassembly would be:

```
someArrFunc():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp

        lea     rax, [rbp-20]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax

        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 451

        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 885

        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-16], 452

        add     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 4
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 886

        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 8

        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Here `rbp-20` is the start address of the `arr` and `rbp-8` is adress of `ptr` value. You can observe from the code that there is no difference between setting the `arr` and `ptr` in terms of memory. The variable `arr` in this case refers to `rbp-20` while the pointer's value is also `rbp-20`. The only real difference between them is that the pointer holds extra memory since we are able to change its value.

I see that there is a decay but it is not relevant to my explanation of the memory structure. Moreover see that `sizeof` isn't stored in memory. It is an immediate value that is placed by the compiler with prior knowledge of its size.

Comment: *`sets the arr to be the pointer to the start of that memory address`* - no it is not the truth

Comment: @0___________ what do you mean? The variable ```arr``` stores the memory address that points to the stored data

Comment: "and sets the arr to be the pointer to the start of that memory address." That would mean that at address `&arr` there would be an address stored in memory. That is not true. `arr` is an array, not a pointer. What you might have in mind is that in some situations `arr` decays to a pointer to first element.

Comment: variable `arr` does not store the address of the array. ***IT IS THE ARRAY***

Comment: @Gerhardh If you run the following code ```int arr[2]; printf("%x", arr);``` what would happen? As a matter of fact ```arr``` and ```&arr``` have no difference whatsoever

Comment: That is one situation where the array decays to a pointer. Try `int arr[100]; printf(size=%zu\n", sizeof(arr));`. Do you expect to get size of a pointer?

Comment: @0___________ I don't see how it is relevant to my explanation. In the end ```arr``` holds an address. The address points to the memory which contains the data. Everything else is irrelevant to my explanation of the structure of memory.

Comment: You may want to read this: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) Note that this question is about both C and C++, so you may not understand the references to C++.

Comment: @Gerhardh it is because the size of an array is known by the compiler. The size or other data about the array is not stored in memory per se, it is not a different type of data.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I didn't know about array-to-pointer decay but now knowing it doesn't change my explanation a bit.  Although a pointer and an array doesn't share the same properties (i.e being able to determine size), an array is a pointer nonetheless.

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli: When used in an expression, in most situations, but not all (for example not in the case of `sizeof`), the type of the expression is converted to a pointer type which points to the first element of the array, according to [§6.3.2.1 ¶3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3). This is generally called "array to pointer decay". This does not mean that an array **is** a pointer. For example, you can assign a value to a pointer, but you cannot assign a value to an array.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel those are the things done by the compiler. They have no significance in the structure of the memory.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I have added an edit.

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli try to `++` an array :) Also learn how to use the correct **types**. `int abc = sizeof(arr);` is wrond and potentially UB

Comment: @0___________ ```arr[1]``` already resolves to ```*(arr + 1)``` try using ```1[arr]``` as well. Also, I have added an edit.

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli try `++` not `+1`

Comment: @0___________ What you are saying is syntax-wise wrong. I still don't see how it is relevant.

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli In your answer you say: "...sets the `arr` to be the pointer to the start of that memory address". This statement is wrong!! `arr` decays to a pointer, BUT it is not a pointer. A pointer can be incremented, decremented or generally speaking point to elsewhere. Your variable `arr` does not satisfy this property. This by itself should clarify that there is a distinction between arrays and pointers.

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou my point was strictly on memory sttucture. The compilation of the program or c cyntax is irrelevant

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli I accept your description on memory, it is fair! Your explanation though has a loss, an array is not a pointer.

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou It is a semantic issue then. I may try to phrase it better

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou I have added an edit.

Comment: *" the pointer to the beginning of that memory is used when arr is referenced"*, no, there is no pointer. The compiler knows the address of the array, it doesn't need a separate pointer. Pointer contains a memory address. There's nothing containing the memory address of the array here. `rbp-20` is not a pointer.

Comment: @hyde ```rbp - 20``` is the pointer to the array.

Comment: The memory at address `rbp-20` contains the first value in the array. `rbp` contains the "base" of the stack frame (BP comes from Base Pointer). `rbp-20` is not stored anywhere, it is calculated on the fly by the CPU circuitry (or microcode or whatnot you may have in the CPU).

Comment: You could say "when `arr` is used in an expression, it is often (but not always, `sizeof` and `&` address-of operator being the important exceptions) converted to pointer to the first element of the array" or some such.

Comment: @hyde ```[rbp-20]``` is the first value in the array, ```rbp-20``` is the pointer to it. As I have said before, the issue is purely on semantics, I am not claiming that the compiler is treating an array exactly the same as it treats a pointer. They are same in the sense that an array is represented by a pointer. That is the only thing that is relevant to my answer which only talks about the structure in memory rather than C syntax

Comment: Semantics are important. Words mean specific things. This is extra important when communicating about programming concepts, which have exact technical meanings, which may even be conflicting in different contexts. Array vs pointer in C is _so_ common source of confusion, that being pedantic is warranted. YMMV.